# Bottom Navigation View : Change the default highlighted Tab when the app launches

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

[image: My Navigation View]

As shown above, I have this button navigation view, when ever I launch my application, in default my "Catagories" tab gets highlighted, but I want to get my "Home" tab get highlighted when i launch my application, can anyone help me get out of it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this use `setSelectedItemId()` method of your `BottomNavigationView` like this

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home_menu);
```

or use `viewPager.setCurrentItem();` of your view pager like this

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a start destination in the `res/navigation/mobile_navigation.xml`.

Change the `app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home"` row:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.github.bottomchan.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
        android:name="com.github.bottomchan.ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_dashboard"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dashboard" />
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   /***Just try to use below code snipet***/

   viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
   {
     home_icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon_selected_state, getApplicationContext().getTheme()));

   }
   else
   {
     home_icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon_selected_state));
   }
```