# BottomNavigationView: select non

Tags: android, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview

```
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
```

I don't want the first item to be selected automatically.

How can I do so?

tried

```
navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
```

didn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bottom Navigation View : Change the default highlighted Tab when the app launches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46048657/bottom-navigation-view-change-the-default-highlighted-tab-when-the-app-launche)

Comment: You can use `bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_id);`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372293/bottomnavigationview-how-to-uncheck-all-menuitems-and-keep-titles-being-displa/43341783

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202294/set-selected-item-in-android-bottomnavigationview

Please check this

Comment: I want to be able to select non - not to select specific item as the "duplicate"

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
navigation.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, false, true);
```